# How to modify a single column with joins using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to add a new column to a data frame, based on the levels of one (or a few) factors. I start with a data frame with two factors and a single variable

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data_frame(one = letters[1:5], two = LETTERS[1:5], three = 6:10)
```

And I want to add a new column, `four`, that has values for certain levels of `one` and `two`. For convenience, I keep these new values in their own little tables:

```
new_fourth_a <- data_frame(one = "b", four = 47)
new_fourth_b <- data_frame(two = c("C","E"), four = 42)
```

The correct answer would be

```
    one   two three  four
  (chr) (chr) (int) (dbl)
1     a     A     6    NA
2     b     B     7    47
3     c     C     8    42
4     d     D     9    NA
5     e     E    10    42
```

And the best way I could think of to accomplish this is via `left_join()`:

```
test %>% 
  left_join(new_fourth_a, by = "one") %>%
  left_join(new_fourth_b, by = "two")
```

But this ends up duplicating the `four` column. This could be a good thing: it would allow for easy checking to see if there are any joins that introduce more than one value for the new column (ie check that there is only one non-NA value across each row in all the columns that start with `four.` ). Still, I think there must be an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses join

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data_frame(one = letters[1:5], two = LETTERS[1:5], three = 6:10)
new_fourth_a <- data_frame(one = "b", extra_a = 47)
new_fourth_b <- data_frame(two = c("C","E"), extra_b = 42)
test %>% 
  left_join(new_fourth_a, by = "one") %>%
  left_join(new_fourth_b, by = "two") %>%
  mutate(four = pmax(extra_a, extra_b, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-extra_a, -extra_b)
```

If you want to handle an arbitrary number then you have the handle one at a time

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data_frame(one = letters[1:5], two = LETTERS[1:5], three = 6:10)
new_fourth_a <- data_frame(one = "b", extra = 47)
new_fourth_b <- data_frame(two = c("C","E"), extra = 42)
test %>% 
  left_join(new_fourth_a, by = "one") %>%
  mutate(four = extra) %>%
  select(-extra) %>%
  left_join(new_fourth_b, by = "two") %>%
  mutate(four = ifelse(is.na(extra), four, extra)) %>%
  select(-extra)
```

Comment: This is quite close to the solution i had in mind (but better! I like the use of `pmax`). However, I have an arbitrary number of `new_fourth` datasets; it seems tricky/tedious to manage to give them all different `extra_X` names!

Comment: I've added another solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two more `data_frame`s, we could use `%in%` with some arithmetic to get a numeric index to create the column 'four' with values NA, 47, and 42.

```
 test %>%
     mutate(four = c(NA, 47, 42)[1+(one %in% 'b') + 
                         2*(two %in% c('C', 'E'))])
 #   one   two three  four
 #  (chr) (chr) (int) (dbl)
 #1     a     A     6    NA
 #2     b     B     7    47
 #3     c     C     8    42
 #4     d     D     9    NA
 #5     e     E    10    42
```

Comment: definitely produced the correct output, but would not scale to my actual problem. I made my example minimal by design, sorry if that oversimplified the problem

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald  Whenever somebody post a question, we come up with a solution based on the example showed in the post.